# Bound on spectral norm of a symmetric matrix with entries in $[-1, 1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with entries in $[-1, 1]$. Define spectral norm in the usual way, $||A|| = \max_{||x||=1}{||Ax||}$. I think that the maximum spectral norm possible for any such matrix should be 1, but I can't prove it.

Writing $||Ax||^2 = \Sigma_i{(\Sigma_j{a_{ij}x_j})^2}$, I got the bound to be $\sqrt{n}$. Is there a better upper bound on the spectral norm of such matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bound is wrong: let all entries of $A$ be equal to $+1$. Let $v$ be the vector with all entries equal to $+1$. Then $Av=n\cdot v$ so $\|Av\| = n \|v\|$.